# Clarification of the proof involving the regularity condition in Master Theorem

Tags: algorithm-analysis, proof-techniques, master-theorem

I was going the text Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen et al. Where I came across the following statement in the proof of the third case of the Master's Theorem.

> (The Statement of Master theorem) Let $a \geqslant 1$ and $b > 1$ be constants, let $f(n)$ be a function, and let $T (n)$ be deﬁned on the nonnegative integers by the recurrence( the recursion divides a problem of size $n$ into $a$ problems of size $n/b$ each and takes $f(n)$ for the divide and combine)
>
> $T(n) = aT(n/b)+ f (n)$ ;
>
> where we interpret $n/b$ to mean either $\lceil b/n \rceil$ or $\lfloor b/n \rfloor$. Then $T(n)$ has the following asymptotic bounds:
>
> 1. If $f(n)=O (n^{\log_ba - \epsilon})$ for some constant $\epsilon > 0$, then $T(n)=\Theta (n^{\log_ba})$.
> 2. If $f(n)=\Theta (n^{\log_ba})$, then $T(n)=\Theta (n^{\log_ba}\lg n)$
> 3. If $f(n)=\Omega (n^{\log_ba + \epsilon})$ for some constant $\epsilon > 0$, and if $af(n/b) \leqslant cf(n)$ for some constant $c < 1$ and all sufﬁciently large n, then $T(n)=\Theta (f(n))$.

For $n$ as exact powers of $b$ we restrict the domain of T(n) as follows:

> $$T(n)= \Theta(1), n=1$$
> $$T(n)=aT(n/b)+f(n) ,n=b^i$$

Now in the proof of Master's Theorem with *$n$ as exact power of $b$* the expression for $T(n)$ reduces to :

$$T(n)=\Theta(n^{\log_ba})+\sum_{j=0}^{\log_bn -1} a^jf(n/b^j)$$

[image: The recursion tree for the reduction of the recurrence to a summation]

Then the authors assume the following,

$$g(n)=\sum_{j=0}^{\log_bn -1} a^jf(n/b^j)$$

Then for the proof of the 3rd case of the Master's Theorem the authors prove the following lemma,

> *Lemma 1* : If $a\cdot f(n/b)\leqslant c\cdot f(n)$ for some constant $c<1$ and for all $n\geqslant b$ then $g(n)=\Theta(f(n))$

They say that:

*under their assumption that $c<1$ and $n \geqslant b$*,they have $a \cdot f(n/b)\leqslant c \cdot f(n) \implies f(n/b)\leqslant (c/a) \cdot f(n)$

then **iterating $j$ times** yields, $f(n/b^j)\leqslant (c/a)^j \cdot f(n)$

I could not quite get the mathematics used behind **iterating $j$ times**.

Moreover I could not quite get the logic behind the assumption of $n\geqslant b$ for the situation that $n$ should be sufficiently large. (As the third case of the Master's Theorem says.)

The proof of the lemma continues as follows:

> > $$f(n/b^j)\leqslant (c/a)^j\cdot f(n) \iff a^j\cdot f(n/b^j)\leqslant c^j\cdot f(n)$$
> > So, $$g(n)=\sum_{j=0}^{\log_bn -1} a^jf(n/b^j)$$
> > $$\leqslant \sum_{j=0}^{\log_bn -1} c^jf(n)$$
> > $$\leqslant f(n)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} c^j,$$ as $c<1$ we have an infinite geometric series
> > $$= f(n) \left(\frac{1}{1-c}\right)$$
> > $$=O(f(n))$$ as $c$ is a constant. (Note that $T(n)=\Omega(f(n))$ from the recursion diagram.)
>
> Then the authors proof the third case of the Masters Theorem for $n$ as exact power of $b$:
>
> > *Lemma 2*: Let $a \geqslant 1$ and $b>1$,  if $f(n)=\Omega (n^{\log_ba + \epsilon})$ for some constant $\epsilon > 0$, and if $af(n/b) \leqslant cf(n)$ for some constant $c < 1$ and all sufﬁciently large n, then $T(n)=\Theta (f(n))$.
>
> > So $$T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_ba}) + g(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_ba}) + \Theta(f(n)) =\Theta(f(n))$$ as $f(n)=\Omega (n^{\log_ba + \epsilon})$

Moreover in the similar proof for the third case of the general master theorem (not assuming $n$ as exact powers of $b$) there again the book assumes that $n\geqslant b+b/(b-1)$ to go with the situation of sufficiently large $n$.

**I do not quite understand what the specific value has to do and why such is assumed as sufficiently large $n$**

(I did not give the details of the second situation as I feel that it shall be something similar to the first situation but however it can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1kq7H5gb6aFWNyvOPlNOOGroDW6qqKyW5OsXwCVs2aMc/edit?usp=sharing))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the issue of iteration. Suppose that a function $f$ satisfies
$$ f(n/b) \leq (c/a)f(n). $$
Then it also satisfies
$$ f(n/b^2) \leq (c/a)f(n/b) \leq (c/a)^2 f(n). $$
You can prove by induction that for all integer $t \geq 0$,
$$ f(n/b^t) \leq (c/a)^t f(n). $$

As for your second question, about assuming that $n$ is large enough: the proof is just sloppy. You cannot assume that $f(n/b) \leq (c/a) f(n)$ holds for all $n \geq b$. Indeed, in Introduction to Algorithms, third edition, they do not make such an assumption for the case where $n$ is a power of $b$.

They do seem to make such as assumption in the case of general $n$, but what they are really saying is that the inequality $f(\lceil n/b \rceil) \leq (c/a) f(n)$ only makes sense for $n \ge b + b/(b-1)$. Using the idea of the proof of the special case where $n$ is a power of $b$, you can complete the proof of the general case. I would, however, strongly suggest ignoring such technicalities at present. The master theorem is essentially a calculation, and you can trust the authors that it works out. Nothing interesting is hidden under the rug.

Comment: @YuvalFimus I have modified the question with the details of the proof included, I could understand your explanation of the iteration part... Please can you help me out with the $n\geqslant b$ part as you said that answering it required more details...

Comment: This is of no help. Crucial context is missing. Their assumption doesn't imply that $f(n/b) \leq (c/a) f(n)$ for all $n \geq b$, and they must be saying something about this.

Comment: Nothing more is written about their assumption and implication. May be it was weird and that's why they dealt away with it in 3rd edition(as you pointed out). I thought that they might have got the assumption of $n\geq b+ \frac{b}{b-1}$ in same manner as they made the assumption for $n \geq b$. I was quite disturbed as I was unable to make out those two technicalities(which are sloppy and not quite clear). Thanks a lot for the help...